# The Error in the Standard Linear Approximation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $f$ has continuous first and second partial derivatives throughout an open set containing a rectangle $R$ entered at $(x_0,y_0)$ and if $M$ is any upper bound for the values of $|f_{xx}|$, $|f_{yy}|$, $|f_{xy}|$ on $R$, then the error $E(x,y)$ incurred in replacing $f(x,y)$ on $R$ by its linearization
>
> $L(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$ satisfies the inequality

$$|E(x,y)| \le \frac{1}{2} M(|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|)^2.$$

Can anyone give me an insight to what $|E(x,y)| \le \frac{1}{2} M(|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|)^2$ is doing?

Surely it's useful in calculating an upper boundary for Error, but why does that give an upper boundary? Is it an arbitrary value that mathematicians have agreed on or was this derived?

Can someone show me or derive how they got to this conclusion? i.e. ($\frac{1}{2} M(|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|)^2$)?

Comment: Your way of coding in MathJax is really really really bad.  Please look at my edits.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I just started coding. What do you suggest I do next time? Is my coding bad because redundant? inconsistent? vague?

Comment: Look at my edits.  In an expression like $$|E(x,y)| \le \frac{1}{2} M(|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|)^2$$ one should just have one pair of dollar signs or double dollar signs surrounding the whole thing, rather than alternating in and out of MathJax code repeatedly through the whole thing.  That way the fonts and the spacing are all down according to standard conventions for typesetting mathematical notation. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it was derived. Mathematicians do *not* "agree on arbitrary values". It's hard to get them to agree on derivations!

This error estimate comes from the error estimate in [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) for $f$ as a function of $x$ and as a function of $y$.

Comment: arennt math axioms arbitrary

Comment: Arbitrary? No. Changable, yes. We don't agree that a particular set of axioms is "true". But we do find that some sets of axioms are interesting, and therefore will mostly work within the theory where they are true. But it is understood that all results obtained only apply to that theory. And we also will work in theories where our favorite axioms are false, because we also want to know what happens then.

Comment: Could you please provide more details or maybe a derivation to support the claim that the error estimate inequation comes from Taylor's theorem?

Comment: @NihalJain - follow the wikipedia link in the post. Scroll down till you get to the section "Estimates for the remainder", and look at the bottom where it talks about the case when $|f^{(k+1)}(x)|\le M$. In the  case here $k=1$. The only thing left to deal with is two variables instead of one. But if you hold one variable *constant*, then you only have the other left and can apply the result, which gives an inequality where everything still depends on the variable you held constant. Now do the same thing again to that expression for this variable, and you get the result here.